# NSCP++ check_drivesize core Uknown command

Tags: windows, windows-server, icinga

I try to run check_drivesize on a windows server with nscp++.

I already setup check for RAM, CPU and Uptime all is working fine.

When i try to setup the check_drivesize i get back:

> core Unknown command(s): check_drivesize available commands: commands
>   {, check_counter, check_cpu, check_memory, check_network,
>   check_os_version, check_pagefile, check_pdh, check_process,
>   check_service, check_uptime, checkcounter, checkcpu, checkmem,
>   checkprocstate, checkservicestate, checkuptime}, plugins {, 0}
>                       c:\source\master\service\plugin_manager.cpp:475

This is not understandable to me, because the check is at opt5.ini enabled:

> ; Allow check disk
>   CheckDisk = 1

and the needed module is also present in the correct path:

> C:\Program Files\NSClient++\modules\CheckDisk.dll

I was guided by the [knowledge of the manufacturer](https://docs.nsclient.org/reference/windows/CheckDisk/), unfortunately the commands given there return all these errors.

Has anyone had this error or is he familiar with NSCP ++ and can help me?

Thank you very much.